# EF Many-to-Many with iummutable end (unidirectional)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

The model is like Users and Roles

I'm using EF code first approach. The issue is that, I add a new user and link him to an existing role. I expect to have a new record in the Users table and a new record in the linking table pointing to the new user and an existing Role in the Roles table.
What do I get? A New role, a new User and a new record in the linking table.
It's worth mention that it is a stateless application.

I've tried to create the user w/o roles and add them with an update and get the same result as creating the user with the role in it's collection of roles.

The Model:

```
[Serializable]
[Table("Users")]
public class UserModel : PersonModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }

    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; }

    public int FailedAttempts { get; set; }

    public bool PasswordExpired { get; set; }

    public UserModel()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<RoleModel>();
    }

    public ICollection<RoleModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Table("Roles")]
public class RoleModel : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

And OnModelCreating()

```
{
modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Roles)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                x.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                x.ToTable("UsersRolesMapping");
            });
}
```

The Create user Method:

```
public void CreateUser(UserModel user)
{
    var ids = user.Roles.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
    var roles = RolesRepository.Select().Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
    practitioner.Roles = null;

    UserRepository.Create(user);
    user.Roles = new Collection<RoleModel>();
    user.Roles = roles ;
    UserRepository.Update(user);
    UserRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Also tried:

```
public void CreateUser(UserModel user)
{
    var ids = user.Roles.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
    practitioner.Roles = RolesRepository.Select().Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();

    UserRepository.Create(user);
    UserRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// ...
public class UserModel
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get; set;}
}

// ...
public class RoleModel
{
    // ...
}
```

In OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>()
    .HasMany(r => r.Roles)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("UserRoles");
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        });
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Anyway it didn't work still creating the Role record. Please correct me if I'm wrong, u suggest to change the ICollection to virtual?

Comment: Yes, it's just a code from my project. It works fine for me. I don't see your UserId and RoleId by the way in your entities. And since I don't have your repositories, I can't say is there any mistakes or not. Try to create a project from scratch and use names like User and Role for your entities (without 'Model' and the end).

Comment: I think it's just because of naming. For instance, it seems you have "Id", but putting UserId and RoleId. Try to make a simple project from scratch. If it won't work, upload your code and I'll take a look. If it will work, accept my solution and vote up :)